# How to run a shortcode for WooCommerce view-order template

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm trying to insert a shortcode in the woocommerce view-order.php template but it doesn't work.
This is the reference template: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-myaccount-view-order.html

In the functions.php file I wrote the following code:

```
add_shortcode( 'order_view_id' , 'order_view_01' );
function order_view_01(){
$customer_id = get_current_user_id();
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); //I think this is the problem I don't know if that's right
return $order->get_id();
}
```

The shortcode shows the number 0, so I'm not getting the order id which in my case is 40001.

To structure the code I followed these references:

1. [How to create a shortcode for Woocommerce view-order template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273299/how-to-create-a-shortcode-for-woocommerce-view-order-template)
2. [Create Woocommerce shortcodes with order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036190/create-woocommerce-shortcodes-with-order-details)

Maybe I should change the line that affects the `$order` part, but I'm not sure.
I don't understand where I'm wrong, does anyone kindly have a suggestion?

Comment: You need a way to pass your $order_id to the function.

Comment: I have no idea how this can be done. I'm relatively new to this, could you please give me more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution.

After some research I came across this post: [How can I get the order ID from the order Key in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181999/how-can-i-get-the-order-id-from-the-order-key-in-woocommerce/67182262#67182262)

After that I tried to insert this `$order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );` Everything worked fine. Here is the solution for anyone in the same situation.

```
add_shortcode( 'order_view_id' , 'order_view_01' );
function order_view_01(){

// Get Order ID
$order_id = absint( get_query_var('view-order') );

// Then you can get the order object
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

// What you want to see, in my case the order ID
return $order->get_id();

}
```

Here you can find everything you are interested in showing via shortcode: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Remember, I wrote the code in functions.php. This allows me to insert the [order_view_id] shortcode inside the woocommerce view-order.php template.